# Query or ETL process to insert data into fact tables in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, import, etl

I'm working on creating a star schema for my project. I want to use it for reporting. I have used Google Play Store [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps) from Kaggle.

The thing that I'm having trouble loading data into my fact tables. Below is my schema design. I was able to load data into my dimension table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While you don't specify the specific problem related to loading your fact table, I'm going to assume the question approximates "how do I translate AppName to an AppKey so I can store that ID into my fact table?"

What you're looking to do is search your dimension table for a given value and return the key *if* it's found. Otherwise, we typically have a sentinel value to indicate this is an unknown value. Since you say you've loaded your dimension tables, then this *shouldn't* be an issue but it's a best practice.

If you are doing this through SSMS, then you would be writing a query that approximates the following

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Sentimental_Fact
SELECT
   URD.UserKey
,  AD.AppKey
,  D.Positive
,  D.Negative
,  D.Neutral
FROM
    dbo.kaggle_data AS D
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.User_Rating_Dim AS URD
        -- I assume the appname in user rating is a typo and
        -- should be UserName
        ON URD.AppName = D.UserName
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.App_Dim AS AD
        ON AD.AppName = D.AppName
```

If you were looking to use SSIS, I suggest you read the excellent [Stairway to Integration Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) by Andy Leonard. In short, you'll pull in in your base kaggle_data table into a `Data Flow Task` via an `OLE DB Source Component` and then use a series of `Lookup Components` to augment or enrich your data flow with the keys from the dimension tables. Finally, you'd land that into an `OLE DB Destination` (**not** an `OLE DB Command`)